# I created a python browser using PyQt5, yet some videos on many websites don't run, they make the browser crash

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

am I missing something? should I install some other libraries to make my browser work?
basically, I just did the interface. can someone explain what's the problem?!

if you run this code it will take you to tiktok website, apparently videos on tiktok don't run within my browser and my browser only. I tried videos on other websites some videos run and others don't.

I think the problem is something to do with data.. or is there a specific module that I should import?

I tried to look the pyqt5 documentation I didn't find the answer, I will be glad if you helped. I am making a tiktok project here.

here is the code

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

tiktokSite = "https://www.tiktok.com"

class MyWebBrowser(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setWindowTitle("TikTok Stream Lab")

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.horizontal = QHBoxLayout()
        self.refresh_btn = QPushButton("refresh")
        self.refresh_btn.setMinimumHeight(30)
        self.refresh_btn.setMaximumWidth(50)

        self.horizontal.addWidget(self.refresh_btn)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()

        self.layout.addLayout(self.horizontal)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.browser)

        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(tiktokSite))

        self.refresh_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.navigate(tiktokSite))
    
        self.window.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.window.show()

    def navigate(self, url):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))

app = QApplication([])
window = MyWebBrowser()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Works fine for me on arch-linux with qt-5.15.5, qt-webengine-5.15.10, gstreamer-1.20.3 (video backend).